# I can see attribute in Catalog -> Products grid but how to Shown Product attribute in Sales -> Orders grid in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, product-attribute, order-grid

I have created a custom attribute **"item location"** for every product.
It was created in `Stores -> Attributes -> Product`, then assigned to the default attribute set.

So every item has its own location in the warehouse which is shown in this attribute. I can see this attribute in `Catalog -> Products grid`, but I would like these data in Sales Orders grid as well.
**Any idea?**

Comment: You can add by using renderer, but it will be complex if you want to search/sorting feature.

Comment: Best would be if I could also sort by item location or search, but for now I would be happy if I could simply show a column "item location" with its data next to evry product SKU in the sales Orders grid. I have previously added to the Sales Orders grid column product name, but I have no idea how to get the data from custom attribute "item location"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way:

**app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <plugin name="join_sales_order_grid_with_product"
                type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory" sortOrder="100" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/UiComponent/DataProvider/CollectionFactory.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\UiComponent\DataProvider;

use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as OrderGridCollection;

class CollectionFactory
{
    public function afterGetReport(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject,
        $collection,
        $requestName
    ) {
        if ($requestName == 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
            if ($collection instanceof OrderGridCollection) {
                $collection->getSelect()
                    ->join(
                        $collection->getTable('sales_order_item'),
                        'main_table.entity_id = '.$collection->getTable('sales_order_item').'.order_id',
                        [
                            'product_skus' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('GROUP_CONCAT(`sales_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR "|")'),
                            'product_names' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('GROUP_CONCAT(`sales_order_item`.name SEPARATOR "|")')
                        ]
                    )
                    ->where('parent_item_id IS NULL')
                    ->group('main_table.entity_id');
            }
        }

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

If you manage product sku in grid, then you can avoid above two steps.

Now how to display in grid:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="item_location" class="SR\MagentoCommunity\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ItemLocation">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">Item Location</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <filter>false</filter>
                <sortable>false</sortable>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="product_names">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Product Name</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <filter>false</filter>
                <sortable>false</sortable>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/ItemLocation.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;

class ItemLocation extends Column
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepository
     */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * ItemLocation constructor.
     *
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param ProductRepository $productRepository
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        ProductRepository $productRepository,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $productSkus = isset($item['product_skus']) ? $item['product_skus'] : null;
                $itemLocation = [];
                if ($productSkus) {
                    $productSkus = explode('|', $productSkus);
                    foreach ($productSkus as $sku) {
                        try {
                            $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
                            if (trim($product->getAttributeText("country_of_manufacture"))) {
                                $itemLocation[] = $product->getAttributeText("country_of_manufacture");
                            }
                        } catch (\Exception $e) {}
                    }
                }

                if (count($itemLocation) <= 0) {
                    $itemLocation[] = 'N/A';
                }
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = implode('|', $itemLocation);
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Here I use **country_of_manufacture** attribute as an example. This is dropdown. If your custom attribute is not dropdown then you can replace by following code:

```
if ($customAttribute = $product->getData('custom_attribute')) {
    $itemLocation[] = $customAttribute;
}
```

instead of

```
if (trim($product->getAttributeText("country_of_manufacture"))) {
    $itemLocation[] = $product->getAttributeText("country_of_manufacture");
}
```

Comment: I have created the module exactly as you have written.I am getting error on Sales Order Grid:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sales_order_item.sku' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, GROUP_CONCAT(`sales_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR "|") AS `product_skus`, GROUP_CONCAT(`sales_order_item`.name SEPARATOR "|") AS `product_names` FROM `mg_sales_order_grid` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN `mg_sales_order_item` ON main_table.entity_id = mg_sales_order_item.order_id WHERE (parent_item_id IS NULL) GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id` LIMIT 20

Comment: This error means, plugin not working in your case. Did you created new module? or just created my file?

Comment: Yes, I have created module SR/MagentoCommunity with all the files you provided

Comment: Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Did you use table prefix? sales_order_item will replace by mg_sales_order_item.

Comment: Problem was the prefix. Thank you very much for your help. It is working now nicely. Only one problem is left: If I arrange the columns order to have the "item location" on the first place after refreshing the page it turns back to the last place. Any idea why is this happening?